# c++ Comparison doesn't work between 2 strings from buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, comparison, buffer

I have a socket and that reads a string from a client and then searches a text file for a match.

```
   vector<string> resultlist;
   int n;
   char* buffer = new char[256];

   bzero(buffer,256);
   n = read(sock,buffer,255);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
   printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
   readFile(buffer);
   string searchStr(buffer);
   for(int k=0; k<resultlist.size(); k++){
    if(resultlist[k].compare(searchStr)==0){ cout << resultlist[k+1] << endl; }
   }
   n = write(sock,"I got your message",18);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
```

So basically, resultlist is a vector that contains strings variables and I want to compare to see if it matches and then display the next variable. However, my comparison always fails.

Can someone please help?

Comment: i tried passing the buffer to readFile to compare but it doesn't work either. even after i converted buffer to a string in my function.

Comment: so what does that `printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);` show on the console ?

Comment: it shows "Here is the message: 3g" if the client keys in "3g".

Comment: And the content of your vector? How many strings are in it? Consider dumping them to `cout`as you run through the comparison. Also, your code has undefined behavior if the *last* string in the vector matches the input string. You'll be accessing 1 slot beyond the size of your vector as your output value (`result list[k+1]`).

Comment: there are 114 strings in my vector and when i `cout` i can see each of them. it will never match the last string in the vector.

Comment: The point of dumping the strings in the vector and the message was to see if there is in fact, a match. See Nikos's answer below if you *think* there is one, but in fact they seem not to compare regardless.

Answer (score 2):

The strings you get from the socket most probably contain special characters at the end, like `\r` or `\n`. Check for them and clean them out.